# Maclaurin for $\frac{x}{x^4+x^2+1}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

It is ok to use the maclaurin series for $\frac{1}{x+1} $ to expand the function $$f(x) = \frac{x}{x^4+x^2+1}$$
like that: 
$$f(x) = x\frac{1}{(x^4+x^2)+1} = x\sum_{n=0}(-1)^n(x^4+x^2)^n = \sum_{n=0}(-1)^nx(x^4+x^2)^n $$

$$=\sum_{n=0}(-1)^nx^{2n+1} (x^2+1)^n$$

Comment: This is not a Maclaurin series, you'd need to expand $(x^2+1)^n$ as well.

Comment: It is easier to exploit $$\frac{x}{1+x^2+x^4}=\frac{x(1-x^2)}{1-x^6}$$ and $\frac{1}{1-x^6}=\sum_{k\geq 0}x^{6k}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

For $x^2-1\ne0,$

$$\dfrac x{1+x^2+x^4}=x(1-x^2)\cdot(1-x^6)^{-1}$$

Comment: This is a hint to which quesstion?!